# Where should my authorized_keys file be if I want to ssh to `localhost`?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have my public / private key setup, but I don't know where it should go. Should both these files be placed in `~/.ssh/` for my user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The private key stays home. The public key travels:

- Place your private key in `~/.ssh` (local host). It will usually be `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.
- Place your public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (remote host).

While the first step is usually done automatically when you create the key, the second can be accomplished through:

```
$ ssh-copy-id ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remotehost
```

If you have any residual configuration concerning the remote host, you might run into some trouble with this (authentication failing, or *"too many authentication failures"*). To get rid of this problem, you can force `ssh-copy-id` to use password authentication with:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -o"PubkeyAuthentication no" ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remotehost
```

Of course, once your keys are correctly placed, there is no more need for a password:

```
$ ssh user@remotehost
```

You might also want to add some SSH configuration in `~/.ssh/config` to make it even simpler:

```
Host [custom name for the remote machine]
    Hostname [remote hostname or IP]
    User [remote username]
    IdentityFile /home/[your local user]/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Thanks to this, you can just type the following to log into the remote host:

```
$ ssh [custom name for the remote machine]
```

Edit: if both machines (local and remote) are the same, you can simplify the procedure with:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This will append your public key to the `authorized_keys` file. Of course, another way to log as someone else on your local machine is to use:

```
$ su [another user]
```

This will save you the SSH transaction where you might not need it. [Password-less `su` can be set up using `sudo`](https://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux):

```
$ sudo -iu [another user]
```

Comment: Is this the same if I want to `ssh localhost`?

Comment: @MrDuk In this case, both the local and remote ends are the same machine. Therefore, you must have your public key inside `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` locally. For this, you can just use `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I edited my answer.

Comment: Maybe things have changed since your answer but I needed to add a `-i` to your first command, so that the whole command looks like `$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remotehost`.